# Why can't I add an attribute to my constructor?

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor

```
public class Ouvrier extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final int numOuvrier; 
    public Ouvrier(int numOuvrier) {
        initComponents();
        this.numOuvrier=numOuvrier;        
    }



  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ouvrier().setVisible(true);
            }
       });
}
```

I have added an attribute to a constructor and an error appears in the main frame - why is that?

Comment: can you post the error message, please?

Comment: What error appears?

Comment: It's clear `new Ouvrier().setVisible(true);` It expects `numOuvrier`

Comment: but what i have to write on it i mean the constructor

Comment: you need to pass the parameter which is int ytpe

Answer (score 0):

```
  new Ouvrier(0).setVisible(true);
```

I dont know what numOuvrier means, but you need pass it.